# Accessing ArcGIS Resources for 10.3 and 10.4

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I feel a stupid having to ask this question, but I have tried to find the new help pages for ArcGIS for a while now.

Usually I go to this page: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/ to find info about functions and such. And it contains information for 10.2 and older versions. However, I now have 10.3 on my computer, and while I suppose the differences aren't that huge I'd still like to use the updated version. (Would be *so* annoying trying to solve something, only to find out that it's not working because of an update.)

Nowadays, the linked page displays this text:

> ArcGIS 10.3 and 10.4 web help and administrative guides (such as
>   system requirements and installation guides), are now available as
>   part of the new ArcGIS websites. What remains on this website is an
>   archive of older help systems.

Links to 10.3 and 10.4 only takes me to "What's new"-pages, and, after clicking around looking for "tools" and "documentation" and similar it then takes me back to the same page as above or info about functions in general.

It doesn't help that each page I try to load takes 3-4 minutes to display (maybe that's just me?).

**TL;DR**
All I want is to find the equivalent of this page http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000050000000 but for 10.3.

Comment: Well it's not just you for pages taking an age to load

Comment: This looks promising http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-general-toolset.htm but I'm loosing the will to live wait for it to respond. it's almost like Esri don't want to help you

Comment: I think you might be on to something, you should turn that into an answer :) And ESRI should really do something about those insane response times. Chrome even asks me if I want to close those tabs because of no response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that it can be tough to find things when the documentation portions are being moved around all the time :)

This is the page of the 10.3/10.4 Desktop Help: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/get-started/main/get-started-with-arcmap.htm

The navigation experience is different comparing to the 10.2 Desktop Help: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Welcome_to_the_ArcGIS_Help_Library/00qn0000001p000000/. One of the main differences is that to navigate between the sections, you have to wait for the pages to be loaded in 10.3. In 10.2, you can expand/collapse all the sections before actually deciding to read individual pages.

Frankly speaking, navigating around 10.3 Help takes too much time, so I spend most of time in the offline help that is installed with ArcGIS Desktop.

Regarding the slow response time for 10.3 Help, I have also experienced serious lagging and unresponsive pages. This does happen occasionally and might be related to the maintenance work done on the Esri side.

Comment: Thank you Alex. I guess I just didn't understand how to use the page... I agree that most of the time it's not worth navigating in the help (especially those days with long response times). However, it is sometimes useful being able to link to a tools help page, for example in answers here or to colleagues. And I was quite confused in general that I couldn't seem to find it :)

Comment: Sharing a web link is useful.. Another helpful post https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/02/08/help-content-for-arcgis-10-4-is-live/. When searching in the Help system, I have a bookmark in my favorite web browser with the google page https://www.google.com/#q=site:desktop.arcgis.com and then I do all my searches from there. The Esri's new help system is not yet indexed properly, so I always search through Esri help with the Google :D